# Solving the matrix equation AB = BC, for known A and C

Tags: python, matlab

I want to find a positive integer matrix B such that AB = BC, where A and C are positive integer matrix with a common eigenvalue. In this case, there exists solution, but it is not unique; I need only one solution.

Anyone know a function in python or matlab that do this? I know I can put this as a linear system in the entries B_ij of B, but I am curious about a premade function.

Comment: The matrices can be multiplied and equal as you show only if A and C are square matrices. Are they required to be the same size?

Comment: A and C need not to have the same dimensions, but both are square matrix.
Another detail is that I need the solution when A and C have a common eigenvalue

Comment: If A and C are both square matrix, this equation can be solve if and only if A and C have no common eigenvalue. So if I understand your question correctly this equation can not be solved. You should edit your question and add the condition "have a common eigenvalue" because it's clearly not a detail !

Comment: thanks for the commentary!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a form of Sylvester equations, look here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_sylvester.html#scipy.linalg.solve_sylvester

Comment: I need the solution exactly when A and C have a common eigenvalue :(

Comment: I can't find much about your specific case in numpy or scipy. Though there a some papers about this giving explicit solutions.

Comment: @VeridianDynamics what about checking for eigenvalues before using this scipy library